# Measure CPU / RAM usage of a program

Tags: windows, visual-studio, performance

could anyone suggest a way (other than using Task Manager) to track and log a program's usage of CPU and RAM in order to profile its performance?

I'm working under Windows.

Something generic would be useful. A more specific request solution would involve Visual Studio. I've tried Performance Wizard, but it doesn't seem to give me the information I need. Thanks

Comment: What are you going to use the performance data for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) can be useful.

Comment: does it also serves memory usage?

Comment: It really seems what I'm looking for, but can it "record" the history of a process or similar?

Comment: The Windows Performance Toolkit (described below) builds a record of performance issues, and can capture stack traces of problematic areas.

Answer (score 3):

You can use perfmon utility to gather various counters

Comment: can you record its data or it is onlt runtime?

Comment: You can save the counter values and open it later

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are published APIs for that sort of thing. You might want to take a look at [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393964%28VS.85%29.aspx) and the [Win32_Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28VS.85%29.aspx) class.

If you're looking for a command-line program that gets those things for you there is [tasklist](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx) and [wmic](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx). You can parse their output if you're so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft Platform SDK includes the [Windows Performance Toolkit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc305229.aspx), which tracks CPU, disk, and memory usage over time (along with a *ton* of other features).  It's very handy for tracking down spikes of CPU/memory usage, as well as tracking down issues like why your laptop won't sleep.

Comment: That link says "contents removed".  This may be the replacement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh162945.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about [Intel VTune](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune/)?

Comment: i think that 699$ for something that *nix's top does for free is a bit too much for me, but thanks for the input!

Comment: Fair enough, I haven't really used it myself but thought I would throw it out there :)

Comment: It has been harsh on VTune. It is not suitable for this kind of task but it is not "top" either...

Comment: VTune is a great profiling tool to make sure your CPU-dependent code is running as fast as it possibly can.  It's less useful to find out why your system is slow.

Comment: @Eric: Since this is stackoverflow, my assumption was that he needed to find out why the program he was writing was slow, not his entire system. Otherwise this belongs on serverfault or superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I view the measuring of performance, and the finding of performance problems so as to make the program faster, as two distinctly different goals.

For measuring, one can use profilers, or simply timers, to get the job done.

For finding performance problems, [I take an entirely different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1562802#1562802).